# How can i create a navigation header component looking like that?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to figure out, how can i create a custom navigation header component, which will look like this:
[image]

I have a few questions. How should i go about making these icons from a png file clickable? Should i extract them one by one from that file and make them clickable somehow? Assuming i have a clean layout of this header how can i set this to be my background of this header? How can i deliver this component to other people working on the same thing such that it will be easy for them to implement its navigations functions?

Assuming our stack navigator is in App.js file and it looks like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import Report from './screens/Report';

export default function App() {

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    /* Nawigacja podstawowa, w stylu Stosu */
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" 
          component={Home} 
          options={{title:'Strona Główna'}}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Report" component={Report} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create this custom header as a component, say HeaderBar.js and then add this customer header to the screen/navigator in its options
Eg:

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={Home}
    title="Home"
    options={{
      title:'Strona Główna',
      header: () => <HeaderBar />,
    }}
  />
```

or add header in Stack.Navigator.
Eg:

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{header: () => <HeaderBar />}}>
```

Comment: Ok, i think i have some idea how to do this, just will need to play around a bit.